# select photo on gallery kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can I change this code so that it opens a gallery and selects a photo. I do not need camera function. thank you

I need this function in my app but I am not able to change that part of the code. Someone could help me to adapt it.

I updated the post with the modifications you indicated me.

**EDIT**

*error line*

```
val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap
```

> Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:2,
>   request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/48/ORIGINAL/NONE/207210023
>   flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list
>   U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F48/ORIGINAL/NONE/207210023}
>   }} to activity {maps.com/maps.com.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: uri

```
private fun checkPermissionForImage() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if ((checkSelfPermission(this.context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                    && (checkSelfPermission(this.context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            ) {
                val permission = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                val permissionCoarse = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

                requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE_READ) // GIVE AN INTEGER VALUE FOR PERMISSION_CODE_READ LIKE 1001
                requestPermissions(permissionCoarse, PERMISSION_CODE_WRITE) // GIVE AN INTEGER VALUE FOR PERMISSION_CODE_WRITE LIKE 1002
            } else {
                pickImageFromGallery()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE) // GIVE AN INTEGER VALUE FOR IMAGE_PICK_CODE LIKE 1000
    }

    /**
     * Save the picture to the thumbnail after taking it
     */
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap
                this.imgThumb!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                this.pictureTaken = true
            } catch (e:IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error loading image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun createImageFile(): File {
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val imageFileName: String = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
        val storageDir: File = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        if(!storageDir.exists()) storageDir.mkdirs()
        val imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir)
        imageFilePath = imageFile.absolutePath
        return imageFile
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you have to check for storage permission:

```
private fun checkPermissionForImage() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if ((checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            && (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
        ) {
            val permission = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            val permissionCoarse = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE_READ) // GIVE AN INTEGER VALUE FOR PERMISSION_CODE_READ LIKE 1001
            requestPermissions(permissionCoarse, PERMISSION_CODE_WRITE) // GIVE AN INTEGER VALUE FOR PERMISSION_CODE_WRITE LIKE 1002
        } else {
            pickImageFromGallery()
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, If the permission is granted, I am accessing a method named `pickImageFromGallery()`. This is for accessing the gallery in order to choose image:

```
private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    intent.type = "image/*"
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE) // GIVE AN INTEGER VALUE FOR IMAGE_PICK_CODE LIKE 1000
}
```

Now, you have to override the `onActivityResult` method. This will return your selected image `URI`.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE) {
        // I'M GETTING THE URI OF THE IMAGE AS DATA AND SETTING IT TO THE IMAGEVIEW
        imageView.setImageURI(data?.data)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, give this error on selected img, Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:2, request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/48/ORIGINAL/NONE/207210023 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F48/ORIGINAL/NONE/207210023} }} to activity {maps.com/maps.com.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri

Comment: I updated the post with the modifications you indicated me.

Comment: Make sure you have added these permissions in manifest file:

```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />```

and used same IMAGE_PICK_CODE (same integer value) in `pickImageFromGallery()` and `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I have the permissions on the manifest I do not understand why it does not work.